# MySQLI + PHP Update/Select with bind_param posting but not echoing

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been hacking away at this all day with only a successful 'UPDATE' to show for it. I am new to using MySQLI and seem to be encountering several issues with the script.

A volunteer uses an html form to input their email address, which is already in the database. Then the database reveals their schedule information and updates the 'confirmed' column from (default) 'NO' to 'YES'.

The update is showing as confirmed "YES" in the database, however the output isn't echoing on the page itself.

Here's the PHP: http://pastebin.com/KSPGuuae

```
Errors: UPDATE FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { } 
        select FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (0) { }
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
/home/content/79/6007279/html/summerfest/display.php on line 119: 

119:  $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to run `$stmt->execute()` before trying to fetch the result.

Also, `get_result()` was only introduced in PHP 5.3

For prior PHP versions you should use this query:

```
SELECT agreeName, position, shift_times, confirmed FROM volConfirm ... etc
```

Then inside PHP:

```
// bind result columns
$stmt->bind_result($agreeName, $position, $shift_times, $confirmed);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // use $agreeName, $position, etc.
}
```

I prefer the way PDO works, though with PHP 5.3 at least mysqli is more workable.

Comment: The `get_result`, as opposed to `bind_result` was only introduced in PHP 5.3 ;-)

Comment: Wee! UPDATE FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { } select FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (0) { }
Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_result() in /home/content/79/6007279/html/summerfest/display.php on line 121

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /home/content/79/6007279/html/summerfest/display.php on line 122

Comment: Tell me Jack- I am new to learning mysqli. Should I head straight to learning PDO instead? I'm so close to getting this going (deadline is...tomorrow) but I want to learn it right dangit. I'm going in circles...

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I updated the pastebin w/ your changes. Although the database is updating to 'confirmed', still no output on the 'user's' end.  I'm still getting this dreadful error: UPDATE FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { } select FAILED: () object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (0) { }

Comment: **First**: inside the `while` you should use `$agreeName`, not `$row['agreeName']` ... **Second**: those errors are shown because there's no `if` condition around them.

Comment: You don't even know...tears of joy/relief/disbelief that it's alive and working. AHHHHHH! Thanks so much Jack! I don't like mysqli. Will study PDO. This volunteer form will be obsolete after June 3 anyways. Big XOXOs.